# From book : Putnam and beyond

Tags: reference-request, contest-math

Original at https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zn8RE.jpg

**Lucas' theorem.**  *The zeros of the derivative $P'(z)$ of a polynomial $P(z)$ lie in the convex hull of the zeros of $P(z)$.*

*Proof.*  Because any convex domain can be obtained as the intersection of half-planes, it suffices to show that if the zeros of $P(z)$ lie in an open half-plane, then the zeros of $P'(z)$ lie in that half-plane as well.  Moreover, by rotating and translating the variable $z$ we can further reduce the problem to the case in which the zeros of $P(z)$ lie in the upper half plane $\text{Im } z > 0$.  Here $\text{Im } z$ denotes the imaginary part.

So let $z_1, z_2, \ldots, z_n$ be the (not necessarily distinct) zeros of $P(z)$, which by hypothesis have positive imaginary part.  If $\text{Im } w \leq 0$, then $\text{Im } \frac{1}{w-z_k} > 0$, for $k = 1, \ldots, n$, and therefore

$$
\text{Im } \frac{P'(w)}{P(w)} = \sum_{k=1}^n \text{Im } \frac{1}{w-z_k} > 0.
$$

This shows that $w$ is not a zero of $P'(z)$ and so all zeros of $P'(z)$ lie in the upper half-plane.  The theorem is proved.

---

We assumed that $ z_1,z_2,...,z_n $ have positive imaginary part. Then if $  Im(w)\leq 0$ how the conclusion $  Im \frac{1}{w-z_k} $ ,for $ k=1,2,...,n  $ occurs?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers. If possible, it would be preferred that you write it out.

Comment: Read the second sentence of the proof again.

Comment: @saulspatz My english is poor but I thing I get it. However, if $ Im z_k >0$ then $ Im(-z_k)<0 $ and $ Im(w-z_k)<0 $ ??

Comment: You've got the basic idea, but the details are a bit different.  If $a$ is the zero of $f$ with largest imaginary part, then all the zeros of $g(z) =f(z-a)$ have nonnegative imaginary part.  (Now you can translate by a little more to get positive imaginary parts.) So, actually we need translation only, not rotation.

Comment: @saulspatz I think that I understood the proof and I want to thank you for your time, but let me ask you one more thing. We have $ {Im} z_k>0$ we have ${Im}w\leq0 $. How $ {Im} \frac{1}{w-z_k}>0 $ occurs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't fit this in a comment.  We have $$
{1\over \omega-z_k}={\overline{\omega-z_k}\over(\omega-z_k)\overline{(\omega-z_k})}
={\overline{\omega}-\overline{z_k}\over|\omega-z_k|^2}$$

Now the denominator on the right-hand side is real and positive, so we just have to figure out the sign of the imaginary part of the numerator.

I leave that to you.

Comment: Good answer.  If Im($w)\leq 0 $ and Im$(z_k)>0$ then Im($w-z_k)<0$, so Im $((w-z_k)^{-1})>0$